# Adding schema EF Core table attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling a bit to adding a schema to a table attribute in EF Core. When running ado.net the following works fine:

```
private static void Reademps()
{
    string sql = "SELECT [Id],[empno] FROM [encrypt].[dbo].[emps]";

    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"id: {reader[0]} empno: {reader[1]}");
        }
    }
}
```

However trying to convert to EF Core:

```
private async Task ReadempsAsync()
{
    using (var context = new EmpsContext())
    {
        List<Emp> emps = await context.Emps.ToListAsync();

        foreach (var b in emps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{b.Id} {b.Empno}");
        }
    }
}

internal class EmpsContext : DbContext
{
    private const string ConnectionString = @"server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Integrated security=true;Database=master;Column Encryption Setting=enabled";

    public DbSet<Emp> Emps { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
    }
}

[Table("emps", Schema = "encrypt")]
public class Emp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Empno { get; set; }  
}
```

I keep getting an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'encrypt.emps'.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SQL - `[encrypt]` appears to be the **database** name - not the **schema** name (that would be the `dbo` in the middle).

```
SELECT [Id],[empno] FROM [encrypt].[dbo].[emps]
                         ********* ***** ******
                         *         *     * Table Name
                         *         * Schema name 
                         * Database name
```

So your EF Core table declaration is **wrong** since it defines the **schema** to be `encrypt` - but that's not the case.

So this:

```
[Table("emps", Schema = "encrypt")]
public class Emp
```

should really be:

```
[Table("emps", Schema = "dbo")]
               **************
public class Emp
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to just use `"dbo"` for Schema  because of `encrypt` is not schema name. It is just `database` name. It will be like this:

```
[Table("emps", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Emp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Empno { get; set; }  
}
```

**NOTE:**

In your connection string change `Database` to `encrypt`. Your connection string will be like:

```
private const string ConnectionString = @"server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=encrypt;Integrated security=true;Column Encryption Setting=enabled";
```